# Test which macro is called in tabular

Tags: tables, collcell

I want to test if a certain macro is called in a tabular.

The MWE illustrates that. But the result is always 'No'.

How can I achieve what I want, without changing macro `\Cl` (which is just a simplified example)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\foo}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\def\foo#1{\ifx#1\Cl Yes\else No\fi}

\def\Cl{\textbf{Cl}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cPc}
a & b & c\\
d & \Cl & d\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\foo` never gets to see `\Cl`. The reason is that when an alignment cell is started, TeX expands tokens in order to look for `\omit` (a primitive), which is what `\multicolumn` is based on.

The actual argument that's passed to `\foo` in the second row is `\protect\textbf•{Cl}` (the bullet means a space in the name of the macro): `\Cl` gets expanded once to `\textbf{Cl}` and `\textbf{Cl}` is expanded to `\protect\textbf•{Cl}`; since here `\protect` is equivalent to `\relax`, the search stops, but it's too late for `\foo` to see the real thing.

Just protect your `\Cl` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\collectcell\foo}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand\foo[1]{\ifx#1\Cl Yes\else No\fi}

% we don't want \Cl gets expanded when looking for \omit
\newrobustcmd\Cl{\textbf{Cl}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cPc}
a & b & c\\
d & \Cl & d\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I've learnt something today! :o)

Comment: (+2) I implemented it and it works smoothly. Thanks a lot!